# Port iOS game to Android

Tags: android, ios, sprite-kit

I have my iOS game and I would like to upload it to the Google Play Store but I have no experience with Java/Android programming so I ask if anybody knows a faster way to port an iOS game to Android without having to program all again.

Note: My game uses the Sprite Kit framework.

Thanks

Comment: MyAppConverter has a free open beta https://www.myappconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there no easy two click transition App for this. If you know the inner mechanics of the game, then it should be easy to rewrite it. Take a look at a libgdx for java.It supports needed libs and allows an easy android exports (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)